# C# - How to insert into a List All Name of columns within a table. SQLITE

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
private void ProdutoCB(ComboBox cb)
    {
        ConnectarDB();
        var listaProdutos = new List<string>();

        SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand("PRAGMA table_info('Produtos');", Conn);

        SQLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

           listaProdutos.Add(reader.GetString(0));
          // cb.Items.Add(GetString(0));

        }
        // cb.DataSource = listaProdutos ;
        //cb.Items.Add(listaProdutos);
        reader.Close();
        Conn.Close();
    }
```

I tried in several ways but I could not, I think the value is coming from CHAR type not STRING

[image: Erro Print]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column of the result of [PRAGMA table_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) is the column index number.

To get the column name, read the second column (`GetString(1)`), or the column named `name`.

Comment: Preciso que são valores e inserções na lista <> [img print](https://ibb.co/jj7Vma)